# How to use useNavigate outside react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Gets list of emails from firestore and checks if current user is registered and then redirects them to sign up if they are new user.

The code is functional(it redirects succesfully) but get the following error:
arning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.

```
 const navigate = useNavigate();

  let hasEmail = false;
  const [emailList, setEmailList] = useState([]);
  const emailRef = collection(db, "emails");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getEmails = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(emailRef);
      setEmailList(
        data.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    };
    getEmails();
  }, []);

  const emailCheck = (emails) => {                     //checks if email exists
    hasEmail = emails.some((e) => e.email === auth.currentUser.email);
  };
  const direct = () => {                         // redirects to required page
    if (hasEmail) {
      navigate("/index");
    } else {
      navigate("/enterdetails");
    }
  };
  emailCheck(emailList);
  direct();
```

Comment: Title is misleading. You are still calling `navigate` directly inside a React component as an unintentional side-effect. You need to call `navigate` in a callback or `useEffect` hook. When & where exactly do you want or need to call `emailCheck` and `direct`?

Comment: need to call emailCheck and direct after the email list is received from firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the email checking logic into a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `emailList` state.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const [emailList, setEmailList] = useState([]);
const emailRef = collection(db, "emails");

useEffect(() => {
  const getEmails = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(emailRef);
    setEmailList(
      data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
      }))
    );
  };
  getEmails();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (emailList.length) {
    const hasEmail = emailList.some((e) => e.email === auth.currentUser.email);
    navigate(hasEmail ? "/index" : "/enterdetails");
  }
}, [auth, emailList, navigate]);
```

Comment: the problem is the emailList doesnt load if i use another useEffect

Comment: @arw_29 Oh, you're quite right. The effect should only run the effect if/when the `emailList` array is populated. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might not run without the proper firebase config but check it out

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bell-kopbmp?file=/src/App.js

Things to note:

Use useMemo for hasEmail instead of emailCheck. This will re-run only when emailList changes

```
const hasEmail = useMemo(() => {
    //checks if email exists
    return emailList.some((e) => e.email === auth.currentUser.email);
 }, [emailList]);
```

There isn't really a point in having this in a react component if you are just redirecting away. Consider having the content of 'index' at the return (</>) part of this component. Only redirect if they aren't authorized

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!hasEmail) {
    navigate("/enterdetails");
  } 
  //else {
  //  navigate("/index");
  //}
}, [hasEmail, navigate]);
```

Comment: the another answer seems to work. Will remove from the component and use in login component.Thank you for your suggestion